# QtCreator and ClangCodeModel plugin

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator, llvm-clang

I just installed `QtCreator 4.7.2`, which comes with `ClangCodeModel` plugin by default on. After my `CMake` project was parsed I saw much better highlighting of keywords in the code and also awesome intellisense handling of `auto` declared variables.

The downside was that the `ClangCodeModel` plugin was buggy, and gave me errors and warnings in parts of code that didn't make sense, especially the ones in 3rd party library header files. So I was forced to turn it off.

I'm wondering if `Clang` can be configured in `QtCreator`, so that minimal checks can happen. I played with these settings, but nothing made a difference:

[image]

1) Has anyone been able to configure this plugin in `QtCreator` so that it can work better? I am mostly concerned about intellisense. I can open the same `CMake` project in `Visual Studio` and I have much better intellisense there, but I prefer using `Qt Creator.`

2) If #1 is not possible because the plugin has bugs, what are the other means of improving intellisense in `Qt Creator` with `CMake` projects?

Comment: QtCreator 4.8 (currently the beta) comes with support for the language-server-protocol. This might be a good alternative

Comment: Probably those settings only apply to the visual output in the edit pane. I can see the warnings disappear when I apply "level0 checks" for instance. When I select "almost everything" option they re-appear instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you took is from the "Analyzer" settings.
The Analyzer performs on-demand checks like running static analysis, clang-tidy, callgrind, etc.

To configure the Code Model, you should go to "C++ > Code Model":

[image]

You also have the possibility to override this settings on a per-project basis:

[image]

In both cases you can, by clicking on `Manage...`, create your own configuration with whatever flags you want:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. Still getting the same bugs. Which option should I go with?

Comment: @armanali I have updated my answer. I am not sure you can have clang ignore 3rd-party headers though. You could also try Qt Creator 4.8, the release candidate was published last week and is available in the Qt Online Installer.